# ros_arduino bridge vs ros_serial

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which is best for for what? What are the differences between them? Basically what my requirment is that i want to use arduino just as a bridge which connects sensors and motors with the ros node running in the main computer, so that the nodes which requires high processing power can be run on main computer. I am using ros arduino bridge right now. And if i use ros_serial does it communicates with pc faster? For example i may be reading encoder in arduino board and than calculating the encoder position in itself, than publishing it which a node in pc will be subscribing. So which package makes arduino and pc communicate faster?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256672/ros_arduino-bridge-vs-ros_serial/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2017-03-11**:
Please see http://answers.ros.org/question/215309/rosserial_arduino-vs-ros_arduino_bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros_serial ist more vertatile then then the bridge, but is uses more code space on thr Arduino, in my optinion the bridge was faster.

but for special needs the  ros_serial is the better solution.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0